# Marklogic WebDav server connection not working after macOS Mojave upgrade

Tags: ssl-certificate, marklogic, webdav, macos-mojave, marklogic-8

All Mac computers at my job were upgraded to macOS Mojave four days ago. Since then, no Mac users have been able to connect to any MarkLogic WebDav servers. PC users are able to connect no problem and so are Macs that are still running older versions of macOS.

Also, now when trying to connect to the WebDav server through Finder, we get this pop-up message: 
"Do you want to send your name and password in a way that is insecure?

The baseURL provided uses an unsecured method for network communication. To use a secure connection, you must use a server that supports SSL."

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a setting in MarkLogic that we need to change?

Thank you!

Comment: Update - we tried creating an SSL certificate template and enabling SSL on the app server. This clears the message about trying to connect using an unsecured connection, but it still doesn't work. We just get the message "There was a problem connecting to the server “markdev2.ptsem.edu”. Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator."

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8330711 - Looks like this may be an Apple issue, not something MarkLogic can resolve.

Comment: I have seen issues connecting to MarkLogic WebDAV app servers using native OS support in the past on various types of systems. The usual workaround was to use a 3rd party tool to facilitate the WebDAV connection, even if just temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Apple issue. We installed the Mojave 10.14.6 supplemental update and the problem fixed itself. We're able to connect to the WebDav servers no problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the primary change is that macOS now issues a warning when you are connecting in a way that could send your password in clear text.

MarkLogic supports WebDAV over SSL, so to remove the warning, you will need to enable SSL on your WebDAV app server.

The [MarkLogic Security Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security) goes into the details of [Configuring SSL on App Servers](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/SSL).

You can also check the [WebDAV Server Configuration Help](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/webdav) for a complete list of the available options for a WebDAV app server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To clarify a bit more, we get the pop-up warning about the Unsecured Connection and we're able to click "Connect" then enter our MarkLogic username and password. It's at this point, after we enter our username/password and click connect, that we get the response that we can't connect.

"There was a problem connecting to the server “markdev2.ptsem.edu”. Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator."